# Why not a more general function than mappend in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The mappend function is just a particular case of an associative operation where the two elements are of the same type. Why no packages propose an implementation of an associative function without that condition?

This would be pretty easy with the multi-parameters type classes extension:

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Append where

class Append a b where
    (<->) :: a -> b -> a
```

Then, depending on the implementation of the instances, it would for example allow to concatenate an Int with a String:

```
"I am " <-> 42
> "I am 42"
```

or add optional parameter to data record types:

```
data MyType = MyType {_option :: Maybe String}

myType = MyType Nothing

myTypeWithOption = myType <-> "Hello!"
```

I have tried to search on Hoogle, Hayoo! and on the web but could not find such function.

So: a) does it exists? b) if not why?

Comment: How is `<->` associative? The associative law would say that `(x <-> y) <-> z)` is the same as `x <-> (y <-> z)`. But if we have, for example `Append a b`, and consider `(x <-> y) <-> z` we would have `x :: a`, `y :: b`, and `z :: b`. This should be the same as `x <-> (y <-> z)`. Again we have `x :: a`, but now we have two contradictions. In order to have `y <-> z` we must have `y :: a`, but `y` had type `b`. `y <-> z` must have type `b` to be appended to an `a`, but the result of appending is an `a`.

Comment: You could try it as an exercise.  I suspect you'll run into problems with type inference, and you'll have to use a bunch of scary `LANGUAGE` pragmas to get things to work the way you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is is [an action of a monoid on a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action). In Haskell this could be defined as

```
class Monoid m => MonoidAction m s where
  act :: m -> s -> s

infixr 5 `act`
```

This is a *left* monoid action on `s`, you could also have a *right* action with the arguments reversed (as you have).
The action must be compatible with the monoid operations as follows:

```
a `act` (b `act` x)  ==  (a <> b) `act` x
mempty `act` x       ==  x
```

Another way how to view a monoid action and its laws is that `Endo . act` a [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Monoid_homomorphisms) from monoid `m` to [`Endo s`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) - the monoid of endomorphism on `s`.

Note that for every monoid you can define its action on itself by defining

```
instance Monoid m => MonoidAction m m where
  act = mappend
```

See module [Data.Monoid.Action](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.3.3.4/docs/Data-Monoid-Action.html).

Answer (score 8):

There is a generalization (of sorts) of `Monoid` in `base`'s `Control.Category`:

```
class Category cat where
    id :: cat a a
    (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

It has the same laws as `Monoid` - in fact, [the documentation explicitly says](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Category.html) "`id` and `(.)` must form a monoid."

This isn't a true generalization, because it doesn't work with the same types. But associativity works exactly because of the restriction on the types it works with.

Answer (score 3):

You can't in general define associativity without the two arguments having the same type. If you try, it will not be type correct.

Comment: To be clear, as @Carl's answer notes you *can* do this... but only at higher kinds using something like `Category`.